# Why are ios app preferences missing after Appcelerator build?

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I have an app that my organization uses for demos, that I haven't touched in over two months. The other night I updated Appcelerator and installed the app on some new iOS devices, only to discover there is no way to configure the application preferences for the app within the settings menu.

Went from version 4.5 to 4.6 and can't find any explanation for this behavior.

Here is an example of how one of the preferences is enabled:

```
    Alloy.Preferences.store_id = Ti.App.Properties.getString('store_id_preference', Alloy.CFG.store_id);
```

Has something about this capability changed? Is there something else that has potentially gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

it turns out my settings.bundle file went missing somehow. issue has been addressed